# Error while converting Akka future to Twitter Future using Bijection

Tags: scala, twitter, akka

I was using the Twitter Bijection library to convert Akka Future into Twitter Future, so that I can use the rich library that Twitter future supports.

My function is something like:

```scala
import scala.concurrent.{Await, ExecutionContext, Future}
import com.twitter.util.{Await, Future, Duration}
import com.twitter.bijection.Conversion.asMethod

 def blockingAskWithRetry(receivers: ArrayBuffer[ActorRef], message: Any, maxAttempts: Int)(implicit timeout: Timeout): Any = {
    var futures: ArrayBuffer[com.twitter.util.Future[Any]] = new ArrayBuffer[com.twitter.util.Future[Any]]()

    receivers.foreach(receiver => {
      futures.append((receiver ? message).as[com.twitter.util.Future[Any]])
    })

    // I haven't used maxAttempts and timeout params as of now
    com.twitter.util.Await.all(futures: _*)
  }
```

The error I am getting here is:

```
[error] could not find implicit value for parameter conv: com.twitter.bijection.Conversion[scala.concurrent.Future[Any],com.twitter.util.Future[Any]]

[error] futures.append((receiver ? message).as[com.twitter.util.Future[Any]])
[error]                                       ^
```

Can anyone help me in fixing this?

Comment: The compiler tells you that it was not able to find a Bijection in the implicit scope. This means that you haven't imported your custom `Bijection` (if you have one) or the library bijection (if it exists), or that the Bijection is not in the implicit scope.

So, it would be helpful if you expanded your minimal example to include more details :) In particular - which `Bijection` you expect to be used here, and the rest of your code around `(receiver ? message).as[TwitterFuture]`

Comment: @J0HN ..  Added some more details and the relevant imports. Please let me know if more information is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is missing implicit Bijection between Scala Future and Twitter Future which can be imported (brought to implicit scope) from Twitter `bijection-util` library:

`import com.twitter.bijection.twitter_util.UtilBijections.twitter2ScalaFuture`

Also, in order for everything to work you'll need to import implicit Execution Context or have it as implicit parameter in your method.